# 405 Error on PUT Request to PHP Script with mod-rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I built an API using PHP running on Apache on a CentOS box. I am trying to make a PUT request to `v1/object/{objectID}/subobject/{subobjectID}` but I am getting a 405 error. When I make a GET request to the same endpoint it works. When I make a PUT request to `v1/object/{objectID}` it works. To simplify things I replaced all of the code in api.php with a simple echo statement.

Contents of api.php:

```
<?php
echo "got here";
?>
```

Contents of .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule v1/(.*)$ v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Below is the PUT request I am making with curl:

```
curl -i -X PUT -d '{"var1":"val1","var2":"val2"}' "http://x.x.x.x/api/v1/object/1/subobject/1?apiKey=somekey&secretToken=secret"
```

The results are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Fri, 15 Dec 2017 03:31:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Content-Length: 359
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /api/v1/object/1/subobject/1.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at x.x.x.x Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following changes on your server:

Open file "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" And look for the following:

```
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Limit>
```

If it is commented out, remove the **#** and add the PUT option

```
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS PUT>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Then just save, restart the server and test.

Comment: I tried this by placing the code into the <Directory "/var/www/html"> section and restarting httpd but it did not work. Is there a better place to put it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was making a call where the API used to be stored on the server - not to where it currently exists. Too much copy and paste, not enough attention to detail. After discovering this extremely embarrassing mistake I realized one reason I didn't think to re-check my URL was that I was getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error code, not a 404 Not Found error code..

In the interest of learning something at the expense of my confidence and my sanity I have opened a new question to find the answer to this here on Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/888400/why-does-apache-return-a-405-error-code-on-a-put-request-to-a-file-or-directory